# Call a specific custom migration operation whenever a model is created

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, database-migration, django-migrations

I am trying to implement this, [http://docs.citusdata.com/en/v10.1/develop/migration_mt_django.html#:~:text=4.%20Distribute%20data,tenant_migrations.Distribute(%27Task%27)%2C%0A%20%20%5D](http://docs.citusdata.com/en/v10.1/develop/migration_mt_django.html#:%7E:text=4.%20Distribute%20data,tenant_migrations.Distribute(%27Task%27)%2C%0A%20%20%5D)

Since I cannot hard code this operation for hundreds of models, I am wondering whether there is a way to automate this "make migration" whenever a model is created and me specifying the "reference" attribute in the model's meta class.

Thank you